# Can I create an item id when adding it to a collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When adding a document to a collection on the firebase console, I can type my own id in or select it to be autogenerated. So far, so good.
What I was wanting to know is if I can select the doc's id when adding it in the code.
Currently the code looks like this:

```
 return db
    .collection('items')
    .add({
      attribute1: 'something',
      attribute2: 'something Else'
    })
```

What I want is to actually select the id of the item being added through the code, instead of it just giving me the auto-generated id. Is this possible? If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Realtime Database of Firebase as suggested by your question tag, you can do it as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#basic_write)

```
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
```

However if you are using Firestore as suggest by the snippet of code in your question, you can do it as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document)

```
db.collection("users").doc(userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
```

Comment: Given their mention of collections, and the auto-id in the console (which the Realtime Database doesn't have), I expect that OP is using Cloud Firestore. But kudos (and an upvote) for including samples for both RTDB and Firestore.

Comment: That is correct. My bad! That is what I get for posting this question and tags before having my coffee.
Thanks for including both examples though!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help !